# JAVA mySQL JOIN 2 tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Hey guys I'm looking to get information out of 2 tables to create a JTABLE with that information.

The tables I am look at are 'shipments' and 'customers'

Where shipments takes the form of

```
shipNumber | shipperID | destID | size | weight
```

and customers takes the form of

```
ID | lastName | firstName | street | city | state | zip
```

The shipperID and destID both refer to a customer ID.

I am trying to get the city/state information out of the customers table that corresponds to the shipperID and destID.

I have tried the following

```
query =  "SELECT shipments.shipNumber, customers.city, customers.state, customers.city, customers.state FROM shipments, customers WHERE shipments.shipperID = customers.ID";
```

Realizing that the duplicate customers.city/customers.state is populating the same information twice.
As previously said, I am trying to get the shipper city/state and destination city/state.

I also tried

```
 query           = "SELECT shipments.shipNumber, customers.city, customers.state, customers.city, customers.state, shipments.size"
                 +         " FROM shipments"
                 +         " INNER JOIN customers ON customers.id = shipments.shipperID";
```

Where this gives the same information.

I am not sure how to reference the destID = customer.id

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: It will depend what you want to show in your data: info from the shipper or info from the destined customer. Note that this question is not about Java nor Mysql, is about understanding your requirements.

Comment: Why would I need a distinct? I understand what that does, but not sure how this applies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual trick is to join with the `customers` table **twice**, once for the shipper and once for the destination:

```
SELECT     shipments.shipNumber, 
           shipper.city, shipper.state, 
           dest.city, dest.state, 
           shipments.size
FROM       shipments
INNER JOIN customers shipper ON shipper.id = shipments.shipperID
INNER JOIN customers dest    ON dest.id = shipments.destID
```

Comment: This worked! I'm not entirely sure of the syntax for 'shipper' 'dest' but could I trouble you for one more sytax related question?

Comment: `shipper` and `dest` are table aliases - basically, since I'm joining the `customers` table twice (with a different condition for each one), I need a way to relate to the two different entities. Does this answer your question?